# How to write a regular expression that allows certain characters to only be repeated once?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that matches the following characteristics:

- n maximum total characters;
- allows `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` any repeated number of times within the string;
- allows `[_.]` but cannot be adjacent in the string;
- cannot start with `_` or `.`

So, for example

- `foo` — good
- `foo_bar` — good
- `foo__bar` — bad (repeats `_`)
- `foo_bar_baz` — good
- `foo_bar.baz` — good
- `foo_.bar` — bad (adjacent `_` and `.`)
- `_foo` — bad (leading `_`
- `.foo` — bad (leading `.`)

I am using JS. I've been trying to figure this out but have had no luck. Hoping someone can help me save some time! Thank you.

Comment: @anubhava I have spent the last hour or so on regex101.com playing with regexes. Too many to show :D

Comment: @anubhava and javascript.

Comment: @anubhava I do not but I forgot to add that to my criteria. I'll add that myself in my code. Lots of answer already without this test. Thanks very much :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in a single regex

`/^[a-z](?:[a-z]|[_.](?![_.])){0,19}$/i`

Commented

```
 # N = 20, range: 1 - 20
 # ------------------------
 ^                 # BOS
 [a-z]             # Start with letter
 (?:               # Count group
      [a-z]             # a - z
   |                  # or
      [_.]              # underscore or dot
      (?! [_.] )        # if not followed by same
 ){0,19}           # End count, 0 to N-1
 $                 # EOS
```

Test sample:

```
foo
foo_bar
foo__bar
foo_bar_baz
foo_bar.baz
foo_.bar
_foo
.foo
```

Benchmark:

```
Regex1:   ^[a-z](?:[a-z]|[_.](?![_.])){0,19}$
Options:  < m - i >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   4
Elapsed Time:    0.67 s,   673.02 ms,   673023 µs
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty nice. Love the formatting too.

Answer (score 5):

Start with at least one alphabetic. Follow that by an optional special/punctuation character. Repeat as many times as necessary until the end of string.

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[_.]?)+$
^([a-zA-Z]+[_.]?)[a-zA-Z]+$ // disallow special character at end
```

Handle the length test separately. Is there a reason it needs to be included in the regex? You could handle it with a lookahead if you strictly require it.

```
^(?=.{6,10}$)([a-zA-Z]+[_.]?)+$ // for example, length between 6 and 10
```

Comment: In my case there's no reason for the total length to be included in the regex.  I'll use this, then, and a separate length test if a regex with the length is much more complicated

Comment: @dimadima I re-read your rules and I'm unclear whether backslash is a character you want to allow.

Comment: I might have made a mistake—I escaped the `DOT` in the character class. Does `DOT` not need to be escaped in character classes?

Comment: @dimadima No, that's what I figured and I had already edited the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't `[_.]` be optional so as to catch `foo` or `foo_bar_bar`? I believe `^([a-zA-Z]+[._]?)+$` is what you meant.

Comment: @shawnt00 i think that positive lookahead allows you to go more than 10

Comment: @dimadima Again sorry, that was another transcription error. I added the `$` inside the lookahead.

Answer (score 3):

The other regexes provided, while they may work, are overly complicated and inefficient.  The following regex will match what you want (excluding the length check as that's most efficiently done with `.length` on the string itself.

`/^(?:[a-zA-Z]+[_.]?)+$/`

It simply says, find at least one letter (or more), and then an optional `_` or `.`, then find at least one letter (or more), and an optional `_` or `.`, etc.

Comment: Does not capturing the group really give that much of a performance boost over the the other answers to call them inefficient? Your regex is verbatim with @shawnt00's regex (after the edit), so I'm not sure it warrants the "overly complicated and inefficient" critique.

Comment: The capture group does actually make a difference. At this point, however, we're talking about micro-optimizations depending on whether the OP is going to run it once or a million times, etc.  To be fair, his answer was simply incorrect when I made my statement and wasn't directly related to the inefficient part.

Comment: Yeah, I made the "(after the edit)" disclaimer to give you credit where it was due; your answer was the correct one. Just felt it was cluttered by the critique.

Comment: Fair argument, I can see your point.  For the record, I've up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple non-lookahead based regex:

```
/^[a-z](?:[_.]?[a-z])*$/gmi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kV1bU3/2)

This will only **allow a letter at start and end** and it will not allow adjacent `DOT` or `underscore` characters.

Comment: Could you please explain that lookahead ?

Comment: Thanks! And I think this is the only answer that takes into account the first character requirement

Comment: This is extremely inefficient. Lookaheads aren't cheap, and in this case it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @dimadima The other regexes do as well. By specifying `^`, which is the start of string meta character, and following it with `[A-Za-z]`, you tell the regex that the string has to start with a letter.

Comment: @brittenb oh that's a good point. I get messed up when considering matching groups and thinking the ordering inside them is not relevant. thank you.

Comment: @anubhava I didn't see the second section, so my apologies on that.  Lookaheads are different than anchors, however, so I'll have to disagree with you there on equal performance penalties.

Comment: Please read again, I didn't even comment on performance part since that is not part of problem here

Comment: You stated "The other regexes do as well.", which means you were implying lookaheads and anchors are equivalent. If I misunderstand, my apologies, but I believe you worded that poorly if that's not what you were intending to say.

Comment: @michael I think that comment was in reference to dimadima's comment just before it.